# Rendering html on top without changing viewport in React?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, render, viewport

I want to render a component `<Top />` above another component `<Bottom />` in React.
The structure is like this:

```
...
[top, setTop] = useState(false);
[bottom, setBottom] = useState(true);
...

return (
<div>
 top && (<Top />)
 bottom && (<Bottom />)
 <button onClick = { () => setTop(true) } />
</div>
)
```

The problem is, when the user sees `<Bottom />` and clicks the button which renders `<Top />`, the viewport changes because there is an "instant scrolling" to `<Top />`.

Is there a way to render a component but keep the viewport (what the user is currently seeing) still ?

Should I use CSS or javascript tricks ?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61346697/how-to-maintain-scroll-position-when-adding-content-to-the-top-of-a-container-in

Comment: @BryanElliott Yes !! But unfortunately there is no answer there :(

Comment: Ohh.. yeah, sorry about that, I only looked at the title of the post. Hmm..

Comment: This article might be helpful, but the solution is not React: https://kirbysayshi.com/2013/08/19/maintaining-scroll-position-knockoutjs-list.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To maintain the scroll position, you can use `useEffect` hook with the reference to the element. Here's a hint:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // keep scroll position of bottom elememnt
  let currentPosition = bottomElementRef.scrollTop // first run
  if (top) {
   // update scroll position when top element is appended
   bottomElementRef.scrollTop = currentPosition // second run when top
  }
},[top])
```

Hope, this helps you to solve the issue.

Comment: Could you please explain how does this solve my issue ? Does the change of ref affect the scrolling position ?

Comment: Yes I understood that, but how does this stop the fact that the page instantly scrolls to ```<Top />``` even if I know the new position of ```<Bottom />``` ?

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
return (
  <div>
    {top && <Top />}
    {bottom && <Bottom />}
    <button onClick={() => setTop(true)} />
  </div>
);
```

Comment: `<button onClick={() => setTop(!top)} />` is better

Comment: yeah I meant that, does not solve my problem anyway

Comment: Why is ```!top``` better ? Is just different logic...